# Has anyone used aruco with unity for marker tracking?

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, aruco

At the moment I'm trying to use OpenCV's aruco library with Unity.

So far I've been looking at;

https://github.com/enormand/aruco-unity
- I'm struggling to use CMAKE here.
CMAKE keeps throwing the error; "project files may be invalid". 
No tutorials seem to help with this.

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=fr&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http://tips.hecomi.com/entry/2015/09/16/014119
- but I'm not really sure about creating the NDK and using it with Unity.

Has anyone done this?
Does anyone have advice using CMAKE?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the developer of this project

Comment: Hi @Bijan it's a personal project I'm working on

Comment: Of course, but the github project is done by Erwan Normand I believe you can contact him thru this link https://ca.linkedin.com/in/normanderwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we have this working, using OpenCV for Unity

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-for-unity-21088

This costs money, but it does contain a very good example of using Aruco tags to do marker-based AR.  So if you want to save yourself some time (and a lot of math) this is a good option.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUVq20Xb4sM

Here's the github repo for the specific example, which is also available as an Android app on the Play store:

https://github.com/EnoxSoftware/MarkerBasedARExample

If you don't want to spend the money, please check the code in the above github repo, in particular:

https://github.com/EnoxSoftware/MarkerBasedARExample/blob/master/Assets/MarkerBasedARExample/MarkerBasedAR/MarkerDetector.cs

This has all the essential code to make this work.